# how to get dummies from lists of elements from a particular column

Tags: dataframe, machine-learning, data-science, data-analysis

[image: dataframe]

This is my dataframe and i want to create a seperate columns (dummies) for each genre(like comedy....) which is stored in lists

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!   please review the guidelines for posting question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You have to concatenate the strings in lists and then perform a `.get_dummies()`

```
df['gn'].str.join('|').str.get_dummies()
```